# Greatest common denominator

Tags: divisibility

My problem is figuring out how to express the GCD as a linear combination of $(9,11)$.  So far, I have:

$$11 = 9 + 2$$
$$9 = 4 \cdot 2 + 1$$

From here, I'm not sure if I put $2 = 2 \cdot 1$

As for "working backwards", I think I start out with $1 = 9 - 4\cdot 2= 9 - 4(11 - 9)$ maybe?

I'm drawing blanks trying to solve this.

Comment: Sorry for the garbage formatting.

Comment: You're right. $gcd(9,11)=1=9-4(11-9)=5\cdot9-4\cdot11$

Answer (score 0):

The key to "working backwards" in these problems is *NOT* multiplying things out. From the last equation, we get
$$1=9-4\cdot 2$$
Then we see that $2$ can be written in terms of multiples of $11$ and $9$ using equation 1. So we get
$$1=9-4\cdot 2=9-4(11-9)=5\cdot 9 -4\cdot 11$$

Comment: How did you go from 9-4(11-9) to 5*9-4*11?

Comment: I distributed the 4 through the parentheses, then combined "like" multiples of 4. $9-4(11-9)=9-4\cdot 11+4\cdot 9=5\cdot 9-4\cdot 11$.